# Best way to utilize multiple instances of a service

Tags: java, spring, multiprocessing, distributed-computing

We have a component called Workflow which exposes SOAP web service. We are trying to introduce a asynchronous processing in Workflow by allowing it to consume messages from WebSphere MQ. We also want to utilize multiple instances of Workflow. So there can be 4 instances of Workflow listening to same queue. The problem here is, how to make sure all Workflow instances are utilized evenly and not single instance is overloaded.
Workflow is completely written in Java. We use Spring and Hibernate extensively. The processes which will be submitting message to Workflow are written in Java. For message processing and MQ, we use Spring Integration.
[image: Message Processing]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ensure that no Workflow instance is overloaded is to have each individual Workflow instance not consume a message from the message queue that will overload it.  In this case, you may not care whether the work is distributed evenly, as long as all the work gets done promptly.

If you really want to make sure all Workflow instances are used evenly even when your load is so light that you don't need all of the instances, you may need to check whether there's a way of reconfiguring WebSphere MQ to distribute messages on a FIFO basis rather than a LIFO basis, or if WebSphere MQ can't be configured that way, to switch to a different message queue.  However, I don't recommend this:  the system as a whole can work perfectly fine even if, at low loads, only some of the Workflow instances are utilized, with all being utilized only at high loads.

Comment: Hi Warren. Thanks for answering. I dont care whether workflow instances are evenly used. I just want to make sure that a single instance is not overloaded which may delay the processing of messages. When you say - 'to have each individual Workflow instance not consume a message from the message queue that will overload it', how would workflow know to not consume the message?

Comment: That would depend on the specifics of your workflow tasks.  For example, if each task fully occupies one processor, a workflow instance could temporarily stop consuming messages once it was already processing as many tasks as it had processors.  As tasks completed, it would go back to the message queue for more.